# Save and restore form data in jquery mobile

Tags: java, jquery, forms, jquery-mobile, save

I have made a form in jquery mobile with radioboxes, checkboxes, tekstfields, multiselect.

I want to save my form data with a save button and want to restore the data with a cancel button. I found a great script `jsfiddle.net/mindplay/yLPY3/`

But when I copy it to my form or I convert the script to jqm, ony the textfields are saved and restored.

Is this a common problem and how to solve it?